# Complex structures, Kähler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I know the following different concepts of complex structures on manifolds:

1) complex manifold $M$, which means that there is an holomorphic atlas for $M$

2) manifold $M$ with almost complex structure $J$, which means a complex structure on the bundle $TM \rightarrow M$, $J$ is called integrable, if the exists an atlas of charts $\varphi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$, s.t. 
$J_{st} \circ d\varphi= d \varphi \circ J$ 
,where $J_{st}$ is the standard complex structure

Now the definition for a Kähler manifold from wikipedia is:

$(M, \omega)$ symplectic manifold with integrable almost complex structure $J$, which is compatible with $\omega$

In my lecture I have the following definition:

A Kähler manifold is a triple $(M, \omega,J)$, where $\omega$ is a symplectic form on $M$ and $(M,J)$ is a complex manifold and $(\omega, J)$ is a competible pair.

We didn't define the term "complex manifold" in my lecture, so I just assume it is meant in the sense of 1).

My question is: Are 1) and 2) equivalent?

How does a complex manifold in the sense of 1) admit a complex structure (at all and then, for the equivalence, in the sense of 2)?

Comment: Yes, assuming that in (2) you require integrability: The fact that a $C^1$-smooth map is holomorphic if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations will be covered in **every** textbook on complex analysis (of several variables). Incidentally, if you define a Kähler manifold without assuming the integrability of $J$, then the two concepts are genuinely different, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400764/is-integrability-of-the-almost-complex-structure-redundant-in-the-definition-of?rq=1

Comment: I know about holomorphic fct. and CR equations, my problem is that I don't see how this applies here: If I try to prove $1) \Rightarrow 2)$, I have a holomorphic atlas. But why does this imply that $J_{st} d \varphi= d \varphi J_{st}$?

Comment: Write it in detail, then you will see that this just means the CR equation: It says that $d\varphi$ is complex-linear with respect to the almost complex structure $J_{st}$.

Comment: Sorry that I'm taking so long to understand, but my problem is here that I know that the transition functions are holomorphic so I know that for $\varphi, \psi$ charts, $J_{st} d(\varphi \circ \psi^{-1})=d(\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}) J_{st}$ but why does it hold for $d \varphi$?