# Real Description of a Kähler Manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

If $(M,\omega)$ is a Kähler manifold, then we have the following structures on $M:$

- A smooth manifold structure on $M$.
- An almost complex structure $J.$
- A Riemannian metric $g,$ satisfying
  $$g(X,Y)=g(JX,JY).$$
- A closed 2-form $\omega,$ satisfying
  $$\omega(X,Y)=g(JX,Y).$$

We can state all of these things without referencing the complex structure on $(M,\omega)$, so my question is the following:

**If $(M,J,g,\omega)$ is a smooth manifold $M$ with the structures $J,g,\omega$ and relations as above, does this induce a complex structure on $M?$**

This certainly seems plausible to me, here is my attempt at proving this:

The only step I cannot justify rigorously is that $\omega$ is parallel. $d\omega=0,$ so $\nabla \omega=0$ should be true as well since $\omega$ is defined in terms of $J$ and $g,$ which is parallel, and we also have some compatibility of $J$ and $g.$

Assuming $\nabla \omega=0,$ we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
0=&(\nabla_Z\omega)(X,Y)=\nabla_Z(\omega(X,Y))-\omega(\nabla_Z,Y)-\omega(X,\nabla_Z Y)\\
=&\nabla_Z(g(JX,Y))-\omega(\nabla_Z X,Y)-\omega(X,\nabla_Z Y)\\
=&g((\nabla_Z J)X,Y)-\omega(X,\nabla_Z Y)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Using normal coordinates we can now eliminate the $\nabla_Z Y$ term and use nondegeneracy of $g$ to deduce $\nabla J=0.$

Now we can show that the Nijenhuis tensor vanishes and apply the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem to get the complex structure:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
N_J(X,Y)=&[X,Y]+J([JX,Y]+[X,JY])-[JX,JY]=\\
=&\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X+J(\nabla_{JX}Y-\nabla_Y (JX)+\nabla_X(JY)-\nabla_{JY}X)-\nabla_{JX}(JY)-\nabla_{JY}(JX)\\
=&\nabla_X Y-\nabla_Y X+J\nabla_{JX} Y- JJ\nabla_Y X+JJ\nabla_X Y-J\nabla_{JY} X-J\nabla_{JX}Y+J\nabla_{JY}X\\
=&0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
I guess I am also fine with putting $\nabla\omega=0$ or $\nabla J=0$ as an assumption but I am wondering if it is really necessary.

Comment: ${\rm d}\omega=0$ is strictly weaker than $\nabla \omega = 0$. Look up "almost-Kahler manifolds".

Comment: I think the last part of the answer of M. Albanese [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400764/is-integrability-of-the-almost-complex-structure-redundant-in-the-definition-of) answers your concern. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038350/must-a-hermitian-k%c3%a4hler-manifold-have-a-complex-structure) is also relevant.

Comment: Thank you both, that was exactly what I was looking for.